# Regex, se a varável contenha determinado character

Tags: javascript, regex

Possuo um link por exexplo:

```
<a href="#sessao">Sessão</a>
```

E um outro link :

```
<a href="https://...">Link Externo</a>
```

Gostaria de saber como, acredito por expressão regular, uma forma de eu testar se meu link contem o "#", pra eu dar um preventDefault que seja!

Answer (score 4):

Não precisas de regex, basta usares o `indexOf`.

Por exemplo:

```
var href = elemento.getAttribute('href');
if (href.indexOf('#') != 0) e.preventDefault();
```

O `String.indexOf(char)` dá-te a posição de dado caractere numa string. Se ele lá estiver a posição deve ser `0`, caso não esteja é um "link normal".

Só para responder à tua dúvida com regex, que desaconselho neste caso,  poderia ser assim:

```
var href = elemento.getAttribute('href');
if (!href.match(/^#/)) e.preventDefault();
```